# TypeScript error is not being hightlighted when Vue framework is being used in IntelliJ IDEA IDEs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm

When Vue framework is being used, in the right bottom corner, **Vue** label before **TypeScript 〈version〉** is being displayed:

[image]

What wrong is in this Vue mode, the TypeScript errors highlighting does not work even outside of `.vue` files. For example, I'll declare the **const** without initialization. Normally, it will cause at least `TS1155: 'const' declarations must be initializaed`:

[image]

But in the project with Vue, GUI will not notify about TypeScript errors:

[image]

ESLint is complying but TypeScript is no.

Comment: What does your tsconfig.json look like? Do you get errors if you run tsc in the command line?

Comment: @Oksana Sorry for late response. I understand the solution by your question. My `tsconfig.json` has not the `files` field because Webpack does not need this. I have did some investigations and added the answer. Please check does my experimental data matching with your company's engineers intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE needs to know which `tsconfig.json` do each TypeScript file obeys.
To specify it, either `files` or `include` must be filled.

In the **files** case, besides specific files we can specify also directories:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "files": [
    "Source",
    "Tests"
  ]
}
```

[image]

In the `include` case, although `"include": [ "Source/**/*", "Tests/**/*" ]` is [valid](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples) TypeScript config, the IDE will not understand it:

[image]

To fix it, append `./` to each pattern:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": [
    "./Source/**/*",
    "./Tests/**/*"
  ]
}
```

[image]